# Sum of Schur functions incorporating the length statistic

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, integer-partitions, symmetric-functions

Macdonald's *Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials* includes
the following identities (listed as exercises on pages 76 and 78
respectively):

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Ex.} \,(4) \quad \displaystyle \sum_{\lambda} \, s_\lambda \big(\vec{x} \big) 
&\displaystyle= \ \prod_{i} {1 \over {(1-x_i)}} \ \prod_{i < j} {1 \over {1 - x_i x_j}} \\ \\
\text{Ex.} \,(8) \quad 
\displaystyle \sum_{\lambda} \, t^{\mathrm{r}(\lambda)} s_\lambda\big(\vec{x} \big) 
&\displaystyle = \ \prod_{i} {1 + tx_i \over {1 -x_i^2}} \ \prod_{i < j} {1 \over {1 - x_i x_j}} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where both sums are take over all integer partitions $\lambda$,
where $s_\lambda \big(\vec{x} \big)$ is the Schur function in the variables
$\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$, and where $\mathrm{r}(\lambda)$
is the number of **odd** length parts of $\lambda$ (i.e. the number of rows in $\lambda$'s Young diagram having odd length).

**Question:** Is the a corresponding closed formula for
\begin{equation} \sum_{\lambda} \, t^{\ell(\lambda)} s_\lambda \big(\vec{x}\big) 
\end{equation}

where $\ell(\lambda)$ is the **total** number of parts
of $\lambda$? It seems natural enough but I can't find such
a formula in Macdonald nor in a cursory internet-check.